# What can be edited on the fly?

Tags: android

I understand that to apply a style you have to create the textview and apply the style programmatically, which I haven't figured out how to do yet, but what can you edit on the fly. Like text color? Background color? What things can or what cannot be edited on the fly from the java. Also can it be defined in the xml and then edited in the Java or must anything you want to change or set be defined solely from the Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) lists the XML attributes that it supports, along with the method names for those that are supported at run time. Just about everything can be changed at run time, whether or not defined in XML (including every attribute you mentioned). The run-time changes override whatever is defined in XML.

Comment: so you can even change the style attribute?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, the answer is "no." The reason is that the style attribute is just a reference to a collection of other attributes to be applied at the time the TextView is built from XML; it's not itself a property of the resulting TextView. Those other attributes can be changed after the TextView has been built, but not the style attribute itself.